# How can I keep object from passing to another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, objectlistview

I'm using `ObjectListView` and the object I'm adding to it is a custom `Class` that I've built for it.

My `Class` contains information for doing calculations. I want to allow users to be able to edit calculations they've already made.

I've tried pulling the object from the `ObjectListView` with the following different code:

```
Customer customer = (Customer)listCustomers.SelectedItem.RowObject;

Customer customer = (Customer)listCustomers.GetSelectedObject();

Customer customer = (Customer)listCustomers.SelectedObject;
```

All of those methods result in the `customer` to become that object. The problem I'm facing though, is if I change any of the values of that class, such as the following code, it reflects the change in that object in the ObjectListView:

```
customer.TotalValue += 50;
```

And even if I run those calculations on another form, by transferring that information via:

```
EditCustomer editForm = new EditCustomer(customer)
editForm.Show();
```

It still changes the object in the ObjectListView.

What I'm wondering, is how can I extract that object, and allow me to edit the `customer` object, while not changing the object in the `ObjectListView`?

Comment: See the notes on the [IClonable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable) Interface and the [MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone) Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customer variable is a reference to the object stored in your ObjectListView, so when you modify customer, the change is reflected in the underlying object it is referencing.  When you pass customer to a different form, you are passing the reference, still pointing to the same underlying object, so that object can then be modified through that reference, even from a different form.

To get the behavior you want, you need to clone your object, making a completely separate copy of it, and then making changes to the copy will not impact the original.

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) for information on cloning objects.

Comment: I appreciate the answer you gave Paul. It pointed me on the right path, and I realized I don't need to do a deep clone, but actually I was able to do a shallow clone with the following code: `public Customer ShallowCopy()
        { return (Customer)this.MemberwiseClone(); }`
I appreciate you sending me on the right path. Just wish I would have known this before I spent the last 3 hours trying to figure this out on my own!